# Media queries in email and Android 5.1+

Tags: email, testing, media-queries, litmus

I'm trying to use a very simple media query, but looks like I'm missing something. My code seems to work in most clients, but when testing in litmus, from and above Android 5.1 I see that my media query is ignored.

I tried to make the most basic example, which can be found here: https://litmus.com/builder/b46c315

Any idea what I might be doing wrong, or how else to achieve to target these android devices with specific styles?

Answer (score 1):

Android stopped supporting media queries after version 4.4.

If you are testing in litmus you will notice that media queries dont work in android 5.1 and 6.0

This caused all kinds of problems for me and I have now switched to a Hybrid template base for html emails that react responsively without the use of media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The Android device on Android (not 4.4) is gmail app. Google has stopped shipping Android with its own email client and made Gmail App as the default app.

To test on Android you can use Outlook.com app but i has limited functionality compared to Android's original app or iOS.